# Output caching still adding Cache-Control:no-cache even when it is disabled

Tags: iis-7

**Background**

A customer is running our web app. over HTTPS and are running into the (fairly well know) IE8 "file cannot be written to cache" error when they try to view a PDF/Excel/word file because the response contains the HTTP `Cache-Control:no-cache` directive.  The thing is, it is not our app (or its config) that is adding this directive.

After a bit of investigating I discovered that the IIS7 page output caching feature can also add this header, for example

```
<caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false">
    <profiles>
        <add extension=".htm" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
    </profiles> 
</caching>
```

will have the effect of adding `Cache-Control:no-cache, private` to response headers.

**My Question**

But the surprising (IMO) thing is that even when you supposedly *disable* the feature (see in my config snippet above that `enabled="false"`), the response headers are still being sent with `Cache-Control:no-cache, private`.

Am I being stupid to be surprised by this (I guess I probably am)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not alone: http://forums.iis.net/t/1152306.aspx

We also had the same problem. I haven't found any documentation about this "feature" so I'm assuming it is a bug.

We decided to just remove the caching tag and use only the clientCache tag instead.

Answer (score 8):

What effectively got rid of `no-cache` for me was adding `location="Any"` to the `add` element, which instead writes `Cache-Control:public`:

```
<caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false">
    <profiles>
        <add extension=".htm" ... location="Any" />
    </profiles> 
</caching>
```

In the absence of the `location` attribute, IIS defaults to `Cache-Control:no-cache`. Other possible values are `Client`, `Downstream`, `Server`, or `ServerAndClient`. Details [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching/profiles/add).

Comment: Grrr, that 'details here' iis.net page, gives it's example configuration `<add extension=".asp" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />` which **doesn't** include `location`, which meant I just started swearing at my web server to do it's job properly and ended up here.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the '.' within the extension attribute:

```
<profiles>
    <add extension="htm" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
</profiles>
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. You probably got it working because you have `<staticContent><clientCache>` section defined somewhere else. When you remove the dot, that add extension become useless, which make the `<clientCache>` section to take effect.

Comment: **This IS correct!** I just tried this "knowing" it wouldn't work because, well, the example IIS gives you in the GUI for Output Caching shows that you must include the '.' before the extension... **But it worked!** I assure you, this is the correct answer for IIS 8 - see here http://i66.tinypic.com/2e249af.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your web.config, it completely removed the Cache-Control header for me:

```
<system.Webserver>
<staticContent>
<clientCache cacheControlMode="NoControl" />
</staticContent>
</system.Webserver>
```